# How to force Admob to refresh on Android

Tags: android, admob

I have an app with Admob ads on it but I find that when I use it the ad almost never refreshes because I don't change activities, instead I just update a text view when buttons are pressed.  I have tried searching this on Google but keep comming up short.

I would like to tell the app to refresh the add occasionally, such as after two button clicks or something like that.  Does anyone know how to do this and potentially have some sample code for it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the new SDK now it is:

```
AdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: Thanks. Remark: In my case this work only inside 'runOnUiThread'

Comment: any difference from `new AdRequest.Builder().build()`?

Answer (score 19):

Old API version:

```
AdView.requestFreshAd();
```

New API version:

```
AdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Also, you can simply set a refresh interval with the `refreshInterval` attribute on the AdView element in your layout XML file.  Or you can set the refresh interval for the ads in your app via your account settings on the AdMob website.

Documentation:
http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html#adrefresh

Comment: For people who stumble across this late - requestFreshAd() does not exist. The later part of refreshInterval works beautifully.

Comment: requestFreshAd() was removed from the API at some point.  However it was available at the time I originally wrote this answer.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative you can also have Admob refresh ads for you at time intervals you specify.  In Admob go to "Sites and Apps", then click "Manage Settings" for the app you want.  Then click on "app settings".  There under "Automatic refresh" you can change the refresh rate for ads in your app.

EDIT: with the new admob interface it is under Monetize > My App Name > My Add Unit Name > Refresh Rate (thanks ripegooseberry)

Comment: I had to go Monetize > My App Name > My Add Unit Name > Refresh Rate

Comment: Thanks @ripegooseberry, I'm sure my instructions from two years ago are out of date--they are for the old admob interface

Answer (score 3):

On new Api Version `AdRequest()` constuctor is private; you have to use 
 `AdRequest.Builder` class:

```
mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build())
```

Answer (score 0):

declare adView in activity as data member , then create Timer Task as bellow in your constructor of the activity

```
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
                }
            });

        }
    };

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 1000 * 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //New AdRequest 

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);


scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        });
    }

}, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdRequest adRequest = null;
private void loadBannerRun() {
    if(adRequest != null) {
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        return;
    }
    adView.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_TEST);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

test please

Comment: Hi Vj Sav, welcome. Please consider adding more information.