# How can I force my app to refresh the ad?

Tags: android, admob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force Admob to refresh on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847699/how-to-force-admob-to-refresh-on-android)

My problem is if my program can't load an ad at the start, it won't try it continously, so while the user is playing with my game, there will be no ads to show. How can I force my app to try to load again an ad? I set the refresh rate on the Admob's site, but it can't refresh itself, if there weren't any ads at the start. I'm at AdMob.

Please help me!

Comment: Why this topic was needed to close? It's quite annoying... I didn't asked exactly the same what was in related topics...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 AdView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

and

```
 @Override
        public void onFailedToReceiveAd(AdView adView)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onFailedToReceiveAd(adView);
            //Display your other view here.
        }
```

Note that your question is a duplicate of [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044501/how-to-make-admob-always-shows-an-ad-on-android) of [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847699/how-to-force-admob-to-refresh-on-android) SO questions. There is a search tool [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=).

Comment: I need it to try to load the Ad. I use it. But I can't load the ad if it first not appear.

Comment: Worse, I just noticed both those links show in "Related"... Well, I guess we all have bad days, no bad feelings required ;)

Comment: No bad feelings ;) And thanks for help.